# How do I set a value of a dictionary to a reference to a value of another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, pass-by-reference

For a game I am making, I want to create an object that has attributes that can be set to attributes of another object (e.g. door.locked = lock.locked).  When I update the attribute of the second object (in this case `lock`), the corresponding attribute of the first object (`door`) should also update.  That way unlocking the lock will also unlock the door.
I currently have this implemented with dictionaries, something like this:

```
class Lock():
    def __init___(self, locked = True):
        self.attributes = {'locked': locked}

    def toggleLock():
        self.attributes.update({'locked': not self.attributes['locked']})

class Door():
    def __init__(self, locked = False):
        self.attributes = {'locked': locked}
```

Then I should be able to do this:

```
>>>lock1 = Lock(locked = True)
>>>door1 = Door(locked = lock1.attributes['locked'])
>>>
>>>lock1.attributes['locked']
True
>>>door1.attributes['locked']
True
>>>
>>>lock1.toggleLock()
>>>lock1.attributes['locked']
False
>>>door1.attributes['locked']
False
```

However, when I call the `toggleLock()` method, the lock's status changes but the door's doesn't.  A dictionary is mutable, so shouldn't `door1`'s dictionary update when `lock1`'s does?
How would I implement it so that it does?

Comment: They're two entirely separate objects with no reference to one another. How would an update in one be affecting the other? The dictionaries named by `self.attributes` in both of them are two entirely different dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, you dont really share the same dictionary, you create a new one in Door's constructor, try doing:

```
class Door():
    def __init__(self, attributes):
        self.attributes = attributes
```

and then do it call it like this:

```
>>>lock1 = Lock(locked = True)
>>>door1 = Door(lock1.attributes)
```

EDIT:

if you want to have different dictionaries and only share the values then you probably want to wrap the values in a class and then share an instance of it:

```
class SharedValue(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val

class Lock():
    def __init___(self, locked = True):
        self.attributes = {'locked': SharedValue(locked)}

    def toggleLock():
        self.attributes['locked'].value = not self.attributes['locked'].value

class Door():
    def __init__(self, locked = False):
        if not isinstance(locked, SharedValue):
            locked = SharedValue(locked)
        self.attributes = {'locked': locked}
```

then you can create it like you wanted, but the code using the value has to change

```
>>>lock1 = Lock(locked = True)
>>>door1 = Door(locked = lock1.attributes['locked'])
>>>
>>>lock1.attributes['locked'].value
True
>>>door1.attributes['locked'].value
True
```

btw, in the specific case you presented i personally would have made Lock a member of Door, and share the attribute via [@property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)
and made the getter, try to get it from `self.attributes` and if it doesnt contain the key, get it from `self.lock.attribute`

EDIT2:

adding example for a diffrent solution:

```
class Lock():
    def __init__(self, locked = True):
        self.attributes = {'locked': locked}

    def toggleLock(self):
        self.attributes.update({'locked': not self.attributes['locked']})

class Door():
    def __init__(self, lock_object):
        self._attributes = {'color':'Blue'}
        self.lock = lock_object

    def get_attribute(self,key):
        if key in self._attributes:
            return self._attributes[key]
        elif key in self.lock.attributes:
            return self.lock.attributes[key]
        raise KeyError(key)

    @property
    def attributes(self):
        """
        Door's attributes
        """
        # return a new dict that contains the keys of itself, and lock (and possibly more objects)
        a = {}
        a.update(self.lock.attributes)
        a.update(self._attributes)
        return a 

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        #nice addition, makes you able to do things like `if Door.locked:`
        return self.get_attribute(key)
```

usage example:

```
>>>l=Lock()
>>>d=Door(l)
>>>d.locked
True
>>>l.toggleLock()
>>>d.locked
False
>>>d.attributes
{'color': 'Blue', 'locked': False}
```

Comment: But, if I do it that way, I'm passing the whole `lock1.attributes` dictionary to `door1`, with no way to tell which key I'm referencing (most objects will have more than just the one).  Should I just pass a tuple with the key and the dictionary? (`door1 = door((lock1.attributes, 'locked'))`), then pull out the value of the given key within `door1`?

Comment: if you want to share only specific items from the dictionary in both your classes you need both of them to point to the same instance of an object, i would simply wrap the value in a class, i will edit the answer with an example

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would do it with @property?

Comment: added one now, notice you can do __getattr__ (like in the example) to access it easily

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing this  (at least what I prefer) is defining a `Singleton`. note that this is valid for python 2.x and I do not know if it works in Python 3.x

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args)  # , **kwargs
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

Then metaclass this to your lock class

```
class Lock():
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def __init___(self, locked = True):
        self.attributes = {'locked': locked}

    def toggleLock():
        self.attributes.update({'locked': not self.attributes['locked']})
```

Simply, `Singleton` lets you create only one instance of that object. First call will create a new object and calls after that will not create a new one but will return you the old object created with the first call.

```
door_1_status = Lock()  # will create a Lock object
door_2_status = Lock()  # will not crate a new Lock, but return the already created Lock object.
```

So all locks created from `Lock`  class will share the same object, thus the same status.